# Is it possible to nest gits?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have project proj1, which creates tool1.

Let's say I need to use tool1 for proj2.

What I want to do is put the proj1 git inside of proj2, so that I can independently manage proj1 and have it update in proj2 when pulled from its directory.

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: I think you're looking for "submodules". Try `git submodule --help`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git sub modules can do what you looking for: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules