# Is nested GIT utilization possible?

Tags: git

I have a project in `~/MyProject/`, maintained by Git, and in its subdirectory:

```
~/MyProject/build/doc
```

it has a HTML documentation, which I want to publish as
`MyProject.github.io`, with independent periodicity.

The trivial way would be to copy the content of the doc subdirectory to a separate `~/` subdirectory, and follow the general procedure.

I want to keep the development material in one repository,
and specifically its documentation ONLY on the github.io page, in another one.
The source I have in a BitBucket repository.
Can these git procedures interfere, and can I prevent it, if any?
(I used to 'push'  the source from my `~/MyProject/build`, and
intend to 'push' the docs (as website) from `~/MyProject/build/doc/html`)

As I understood, git goes only towards the root, i.e. 'push' `~/MyProject/build/` will not be affected.
Can 'push' in `~/MyProject/build/doc/html` affect anything, or git will stop at the first hit when looking for config, etc. files?

Is the idea of submodules applicable for my case?
[Is it possible to nest gits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843172/is-it-possible-to-nest-gits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be possible considering the documentation "[Using submodules with GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/using-submodules-with-github-pages)"

If you declare in your [GitHub project page `docs/` folder](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites) (note: `docs`, not `doc`), GitHub will build your pages as instructed, from that submodule repository.